# Concatenating strings in Python that ignores the delimiter if there is a blank string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame that contains strings and blank strings.

Example data

```
col_A | col_B | col_C  
----- | ----- | -----  
 'a'  |  'b'  |  'c'  
      |       |  'c'  
 'a'  |       |  'c'  
 'a'  |  'b'  |
```

I want to concatenate the columns in a way that ignores the delimiter if there is a blank string such that my results look like below

```
| 'a;b;c' | 
| 'c'     |
| 'a;c'   |
| 'a;b'   |
```

I tried the following

```
df.apply(lambda x: ';'.join(x), axis=1)
```

But I am getting

```
| 'a;b;c' |  
| ';;c'   |
| 'a;;c'  |
| 'a;b;'  |
```

Looking at other posts that seemed to be of a similar issue I tried

```
df.apply(lambda x: ';'.join(filter(None,df)), axis=1)
```

But this gave me

```
| 'a;b;c' |  
| 'a;b;c' | 
| 'a;b;c' | 
| 'a;b;c' |
```

Is there a way to concatenate the columns in a way that ignores the delimiter if there is a blank string?

Answer (score 2):

You can remove `NaN`s by [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dropna.html):

```
df.apply(lambda x: ';'.join(x.dropna()), axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I've tried this but I'm still getting the same result with the extraneous ';' delimiter. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Edit: This works if I convert the blank strings which were in '' form into None which does solve my problem. Thanks. Although I am curious if there is a solution to if there are '' instead of None

Comment: @ASM - Yes, solution exist. Need `df = df.apply(lambda x: ';'.join(x[x != '']), axis=1)`

Answer (score 1):

You can using [`str.cat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.str.cat.html) (It will skip the NaN value.)

```
#df=df.replace({'':np.nan})
df.apply(lambda x : x.str.cat(sep=';'),1)
Out[113]: 
0    a;b;c
1        c
2      a;c
3      a;b
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
df.apply(lambda x: ';'.join(x[x!='']), axis=1)
Out: 
0    a;b;c
1        c
2      a;c
3      a;b
dtype: object
```